# DDD Many to Many Relationships with Additional Fields

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I have a modelcalled `Organisation` and another called `Account`.

`Organisation` is the Aggregate Root for creating a new `Account`.

An `Organisation` has at least one `Account`
An `Organisation` has at least one `Account` which is the owner

An `Account` needs to belong to at least one `Organisation`
An `Account` needs to own at least one `Organisation`

So I was thinking of introducing a model called `OrganisationAccount`

`OrganisationAccount` would hold all the `Accounts` associated with the `Organisation` and also keep track whether one of them is the owner or not.

Is this a bad design? What is a better approach? There are some articles online which indicates that many-to-many relationships can be quite bad with DDD.

Would it be better to maintain two `IEnumerable<Account>` properties in the `Organisation` model?

Comment: You should be focusing on behavior, not on structure. Look at the bounded contexts, the use cases that should be supported in such a context and your transaction boundaries. Then determine what kinds of information you need in those use cases and create a model that supports those. Ensure that an aggregate owns all of its information (but nothing it doesn't need). Don't share models with other bounded contexts unless there is a really compelling reason to do so. Note that DDD != ER design with normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it make sense to ever deal with an `Account` in absence of an `Organisation`?  If so, then `Organisation` should not be the root of the aggregate containing `Account`.  You say an `Account` needs to belong to at least one `Organisation`; can it belong to more than one?  If so, it can't be a member of the `Organisation` aggregate.  It sounds right now like `Account` and `Organisation` are just two separate, related entities.

You may need to work a bit harder to discover the underlying domain concepts at work here; I'd try to flesh out exactly what the relationship is between `Organisation` and `Account` by challenging your model. Can an `Organisation` change owners?  Can an `Account` change `Organizations`?  Can every `Account` belonging to an `Organisation` own it?  Can one `Account` own more "shares" of an `Organisation` than another?

To me, the big smell in your design right now is the codependency between `Organisation` and `Account`.  The relationship is very symmetric, which tells me one should not be the root of the aggregate containing the other.  In fact, based on your wording, the only valid way to populate an empty universe is to create an `Organisation` and an `Account` at the exact same time, already associated to one another.  That's fine if they truly belong to the same aggregate, but then the **only** way to access an `Account` must be to ask an `Organization` who its `Owners` and ... `Guests`(?) are; nobody is allowed to hold a reference to an `Account` except members of the `Organization` aggregate! This precludes an `Account` from being associated with multiple organizations (because then one organization would hold a reference to an account belonging to another).

Is `OrganisationAccount` a term that would be familiar to the domain experts?  It sounds like the name of an association table in a database, but you should avoid letting words like that get into your ubiquitous language unless they're useful to the model.  The term that comes to my mind is a `Partnership` between an `Organization` and an `Account`, and it sounds like there are at least a couple different kinds of partnerships: one implying `Ownership` and one simply implying `Membership`.  If I were in your position, I'd suggest the term `Partnership` to my domain experts, not because I think it's right, but because I want to listen closely to their inevitable "well, it's not really a partnership, it's more like [the next step in the evolution of your model]."

Comment: Thank your for your detailed answer. This is exactly the feedback I was looking for. When an `Account` is registered on the system, they need to also choose their `Organisation`, this could be a new one or an existing one. Once that `Account` is created, it will have permissions assigned to it based on the `Organisation` it is in. That `Account` can change `Organisation`, step up or step down from `Ownership`. DDD is very new to me so still trying to get used to it. Thanks again for your feedback.